# Visual Studio: Opening a solution on a different machine loses already opened files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

Visual Studio 2013 SP2 (all versions share same problem).

If I reopen a solution in Visual Studio on the same machine, the IDE has persistence, namely I am back where I was, when I exited VS. I see the same files open and in the same order.

If I go to a different machine and open the same file (say solution saved in the cloud, on a  flash drive, or on a central server inclusive of all user based temporary files), then I get presented with a clean interface. Basically, there are no files open. Everything is in clean, no trace of previous settings.

As mentioned, the SUO and other user specific files saved locally also get moved.

Question: Is there any way to get Visual Studio to open the project on the new machine so that I continue from where I left off and not have to open all the files again?

Comment: I'll randomly guess that the 2nd machine is operating at a lower video resolution so that the saved window layout just doesn't fit.

Comment: That would have nothing to do with the opened file list. In this case, you are wrong. The resolution on my desktop is HD, whereas on my laptop (150% magnification, as it is 13 inch screen) as a HD-Quad resolution. I also have a second desktop and see the same behavior from desktop to desktop. Both desktops have the same resolution, HD. That should not, and does not, affect open file list.

Comment: I have no answer, but to simplify your issue; copying the entire project on the same system (with SUO, etc) exhibits the same behaviour, at least on VS2010 and 2012.

Comment: Yes, I did observe this behavior on previous versions of Visual Studio as well, just asking about it now.

Comment: I found it, `C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\*.winprf`.  Still have to find an IT guy that made roaming work.

Comment: I am not sure that copying the 3 files (Debug_d24ahiag.b1r.winprf, Design_jmkuljox.w11.winprf, and NoToolWin_ugcp1unw.mmi.winprf) from one computer to the other would work, as the names seem unique. I would have to check the laptop. The other thing is that Visual Studio knows that the user opened the solution somewhere else, so when going back to the original computer, I get a clean IDE again.